# How to parse a string without comma to python list?

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, parsing

I want to parse a string like this to a python list:

```py
"[[ 3.14  2.12] [1.11 2.22 ] [10.0 12.0]]"    # Not separated by comma
```

I tried to use `eval()` function, but it failed with invalid syntax.
Is there another way to easily parse such a string into python list?

What I hope to achieve is to obtain a real python list like this:

```
mylist = [[ 3.14,  2.12], [1.11, 2.22 ], [10.0, 12.0]]
```

and `mylist[0]` will return [3.14, 2.12] and `mylist[0][1]` will return 2.12.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? A list of lists must be separated by a comma. You can form this into a String without the commas

Comment: remember string is immutable, so once you have the strings parsed into the list, you will have to replace the commas with a space if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I got some data from someone else, which are some coordinates of dots on 2D plane.  Now I hope to  convert string "[[ 3.14  2.12] [1.11 2.22 ] [10.0 12.0]]"  into a real list like this [[3.14, 2.12], [1.11, 2.22 ], [10.0, 12.0]].

Comment: Just parse by "brute force" (split to sequence of items in [ ], then split pairs) and be done with it, in 5 minutes.

Comment: @JimWang I have updated the answer. Let me know if it helps or if you need a robust approach.

Comment: That looks like a display string of a numpy array, which isn't designed for parsing. Ask your source for a proper string. e.g. `str(arr.tolist())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` can be used to add a comma after each nested list and number.

```py
import re

s = "[[ 3.14  2.12] [1.11 2.22 ] [10.0 12.0]]"

def add_comma(match):
    return match.group(0) + ','

s = re.sub(r'\[[0-9\.\s]+\]', add_comma, s)
s = re.sub(r'([0-9\.]+)', add_comma, s)
mylist = eval(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

This simply replaces the empty spaces with comma and then using the `ast` module you can convert a string represtntaion of lists of list into list.

```
import ast
h = "[[3.14 2.12] [1.11 2.22] [10.0 12.0]]"
a = str(h).replace( ' ' , ',' )
x = ast.literal_eval(a)
print(x)
```

Output

```
[[3.14, 2.12], [1.11, 2.22], [10.0, 12.0]] # of type lists of list
```

Also, note that this is rather a naive approach since this requires the string representation of lists of the list to be in the correct format.

E.g. this is valid  `[[3.14 2.12] [1.11 2.22] [10.0 12.0]]`,whereas `[[ 3.14  2.12] [1.11 2.22 ] [10.0 12.0]]` this is not due to the presence of empty spaces here `[[ 3.14]` for example.

Comment: won't this add a comma before the number sometimes? The OP's data was `"[[ 3.14  2.12] [1.11 2.22 ] [10.0 12.0]]"` not `"[[3.14 2.12] [1.11 2.22] [10.0 12.0]]"`

Comment: it does indeed. But I believe that string is just an example and doesn't illustrate exactly how all inputs will be like. Either way, that is clearly stated in the answer. Looks like yours would be good  solution for this

Comment: true, the question is a little unclear in regards to whitespace and I agree yours is the best solution when, as you stated, you simply need to replace each space with a comma. I also like the use of `ast`, it may be helpful if you add an explanation of why `ast.literal_eval` is a good option for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
x= "[[3.14 2.12] [1.11 2.22] [10.0 12.0]]"
z=[y.strip().split(']')[0].split(' ') for y in x.split('[') if y!='']
```

Explanation: Splitting x on

```
'[' produces-->['', '', '3.14 2.12] ', '1.11 2.22] ', '10.0 12.0]]']
```

Using condition if y!='' on this split produces

```
['3.14 2.12] ', '1.11 2.22] ', '10.0 12.0]]']
```

Using y.strip() removes the extra whitespaces in the end of each element. Stripping on ']' produces

```
 [['3.14 2.12', ''], ['1.11 2.22', ''], ['10.0 12.0', '', '']]
```

Now, as we can see only the 1st element has our values, take index =0 & split on '' produces

```
 [['3.14', '2.12'], ['1.11', '2.22'], ['10.0', '12.0']]
```